# How to create my own object properly out of stdClass object

Tags: php, constructor, dynamic-binding

I'm creating instance of person according to data that i get from API response.

The data returns as \stdClass and i want to convert it to my own object.
Is there a way to pass all the calls in the constructor and make something more elegant?

```
Class Person 
{
   protected $Name;
   protected $Email;
   ...
   protected $Property40;

   **// Is there an elegant way to do it? Assuming I know all the  property names**
   public function __construct(\stdClass $person) 
   {
      $this->Name       = $person->Name;
      $this->EMail      = $person->EMail;
      ...
      $this->Property40 = $person->Property40
   }

}
```

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __construct(\stdClass $person) 
{
    foreach ($person as $attr => $val) {
       $this->$attr = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx. And if I don't know the property names before. Will it still work?

Comment: Sure. PHP creates class attribs dynamically.